# Why does Visual Studio need both `dllimport` and `dllexport` while GCC achieves the same thing with one keyword `visibility("hidden")`?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, dll, visibility

The following is a common pattern in cross-platform libraries that are compiled as shared libraries with default visibility `hidden`:

```
#if defined _WIN32
  #ifdef BUILDING_DLL
    #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#else
  #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#endif
```

How is it that on Visual Studio we need two different keywords when compiling and when using the shared library, while with the GNU compiler we get away with only one?

Theories:

- Are the methods not as equivalent as they seem and therefore are there pitfalls to watch out for?
- Is the two keyword method on Visual Studio there only for historic reasons?
- Are there some internal technical differences that make the keyword necessary with Visual Studio (for example the way information is passed to the linker)?

Comment: *How is it that on Windows* -- You are comparing apples to oranges.  It is the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler where those attributes/keywords are used, not "Windows".   GCC also runs on Windows.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Corrected the phrasing. Even though I think it was obvious from the phrasing that I was referring to "Visual Studio".

Comment: Also [__declspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284610/what-is-declspec-and-when-do-i-need-to-use-it) is used for more than importing and exporting symbols.  Microsoft decided to use the `__declspec` keyword for this purpose.

Comment: The `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)` has been around for my entire 26 years I have worked professionally on windows systems programming with msvc. So I would say this does have a bit if history behind it.

Comment: Interestingly, MinGW both supports `__declspec(dll{im,ex}port)` *and* can work without it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And the fact that they use "__declspec" prevents them from using a single keyword like "__declspec(dlldefaultvisibility)"?

Comment: I am not an engineer working for Microsoft.  They have their reasons.  If you want to know why, Microsoft would be the ones to ask.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OK, sorry, I just assumed the comment was related to the question.

Comment: @drescherjm -- `__declspec` has been around for at least 30 years.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846822/why-does-msvc-visual-c-need-separate-dllimport-and-dllexport-attributes-and?rq=2), although the answer there covers only half the question.